# how to perform complex sql query using a view, rather than by relying on an intermediate (concrete) table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, inner-join

SQL fans:

I'm trying to get dredge up some of my rusty sql skills by playing with the following use case:

say we have are a cable company, and have db tables that track:

- tv shows,
- customers who watch our shows, and
- watch events  (date when a particualr customer watched a particular show).

And let's say we want a report of how many views each show received, and the average age of 
the viewer. The key thing I realized here is that if the same person watches a show X twice on different dates
we can't have this person's age contribute two times to the 'average age of viewer for show X' calculation.

First I define my tables and stick some data in them (this is mysql syntax, b.t.w):

```
    drop table if exists shows ;

    create table shows (
        showid int   not null,
        showname varchar(256) not null,
        primary key (showid)
    );


    drop table if exists cust ;

    create table cust (
        custid int   not null,
        custname varchar(256) not null,
        age int   not null,
        primary key (custid)
    );

    drop table if exists watched ;

    create table watched (
        date   int   not null,
        showid int   not null,
        custid int   not null,
        primary key (custid, showid, date)
    );


    insert into shows values (1, 'bingo');
    insert into shows values (2, 'animals');


    insert into cust values (1, 'joe', 20);
    insert into cust values (2, 'bob', 30);
    insert into cust values (3, 'mary', 40);


    insert into cust values (4, 'lou', 20);

                              # date  / show /     cust 

    insert into watched values (1,       1,         1);  
    insert into watched values (1,       1,         2);
    insert into watched values (1,       1,         3);
    insert into watched values (2,       2,         2);

    insert into watched values (2,       1,         1);
    insert into watched values (3,       1,         1);
    insert into watched values (4,       1,         1);
    insert into watched values (1,       1,         4);
```

now I create a query that joins up the tables and gives me the showname, and age of each customer 
who viewed a show.

```
     select date, shows.showid, cust.custid, showname, age  from 
        ->                       watched 
        ->                           inner join
        ->                       cust
        ->                           on cust.custid = watched.custid
        ->                               inner join 
        ->                                   shows
        ->                               on shows.showid = watched.showid    ;
    +------+--------+--------+----------+-----+
    | date | showid | custid | showname | age |
    +------+--------+--------+----------+-----+
    |    1 |      1 |      1 | bingo    |  20 |
    |    2 |      1 |      1 | bingo    |  20 |
    |    3 |      1 |      1 | bingo    |  20 |
    |    4 |      1 |      1 | bingo    |  20 |
    |    1 |      1 |      2 | bingo    |  30 |
    |    1 |      1 |      3 | bingo    |  40 |
    |    1 |      1 |      4 | bingo    |  20 |
    |    2 |      2 |      2 | animals  |  30 |
    +------+--------+--------+----------+-----+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But note that customer id 1 appears multiple times as the watcher
of the 'bingo' show, and i want him counted only once.

so, i create a query that  lists shows and customers who viewed them, 
but only counts each customer one time.

```
    mysql>  select age, showname, showid, custid  from 
        ->              ( select date, shows.showid, cust.custid, showname, age  from 
        ->                  watched 
        ->                      inner join
        ->                  cust
        ->                      on cust.custid = watched.custid
        ->                          inner join 
        ->                              shows
        ->                          on shows.showid = watched.showid    
        ->              ) as VIEWS
        ->          group by custid, showname;
    +-----+----------+--------+--------+
    | age | showname | showid | custid |
    +-----+----------+--------+--------+
    |  20 | bingo    |      1 |      1 |
    |  30 | animals  |      2 |      2 |
    |  30 | bingo    |      1 |      2 |
    |  40 | bingo    |      1 |      3 |
    |  20 | bingo    |      1 |      4 |
    +-----+----------+--------+--------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Next  -- and (HERE'S THE THING I HOPE YOU CAN ADVISE ME ON)...
I tried to create a view  that gives me the name of each show viewed, the average age of those who watched the show, and the show id.
I planned to join that with a query that gave me a count of the views for each show.  But the view creation failed as shown:

```
    mysql> create view viewages as 
        -> select showname, avg(age), showid
        ->       from 
        ->          (select age, showname, showid, custid  from 
        ->              ( select date, shows.showid, cust.custid, showname, age  from 
        ->                  watched 
        ->                      inner join
        ->                  cust
        ->                      on cust.custid = watched.custid
        ->                          inner join 
        ->                              shows
        ->                          on shows.showid = watched.showid    
        ->              ) as VIEWS
        ->          group by custid, showname)
        ->              as DISTINCT_CUST_VIEWS
        ->          group by showname;
    ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

OK.. so that didnt' work.     I got it to work, but the way I did it seems cheesy. I use an intermediate table.

Is there a sql rock star who can show me a better way to do this, without the table.. Maybe with a view, like I tried
to create, or something even better.?

Here is my lame solution:

```
drop table if exists viewage ;

create table viewage (
    showname varchar(256) not null,
    avg_age   float  not null,
    showid    int    not null
);

insert into viewage 
select showname, avg(age), showid
      from 
         (select age, showname, showid, custid  from 
             ( select date, shows.showid, cust.custid, showname, age  from 
                 watched 
                     inner join
                 cust
                     on cust.custid = watched.custid
                         inner join 
                             shows
                         on shows.showid = watched.showid    
             ) as VIEWS
         group by custid, showname)
             as DISTINCT_CUST_VIEWS
         group by showname;


##  Finally join the table with average age for each show with a query that does the count of views for each show:



drop table if exists viewage ;

create table viewage (
    showname varchar(256) not null,
    avg_age   float  not null,
    showid    int    not null
);

insert into viewage 
select showname, avg(age), showid
      from 
         (select age, showname, showid, custid  from 
             ( select date, shows.showid, cust.custid, showname, age  from 
                 watched 
                     inner join
                 cust
                     on cust.custid = watched.custid
                         inner join 
                             shows
                         on shows.showid = watched.showid    
             ) as VIEWS
         group by custid, showname)
             as DISTINCT_CUST_VIEWS
         group by showname;



select count(*), showname, avg_age from  
  watched 
    inner join 
  viewage
    on viewage.showid = watched.showid 
    group by showname;




+----------+----------+---------+
| count(*) | showname | avg_age |
+----------+----------+---------+
|        1 | animals  |      30 |
|        7 | bingo    |    27.5 |
+----------+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

-chris

Comment: Thanks for the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to create a view that gives me the name of each show viewed,
>   the average age of those who watched the show, and the show id.

The error message is clear--[Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html)

Here's one way to approach this particular problem.

```
-- Age of each show's customers.
create or replace view show_cust_ages as 
select distinct watched.showid, cust.custid, cust.age
from watched 
inner join cust  on cust.custid = watched.custid;

-- Average age of show's customers. This queries the previous view.
create or replace view show_avg_ages as
select showid, avg(age) avg_age
from show_cust_ages
group by showid;

-- Your goal.
create or replace view show_name_avg_ages as
select t1.showid, t2.showname, t1.avg_age
from show_avg_ages t1
inner join shows t2 on t2.showid = t1.showid;
```

In production, I'd spend more time thinking about the names of things than I did here.

You should know that in MySQL, views based on views might perform poorly on big tables.